# Getting exit code out of multiple commands in an assignment

Tags: python, bash, pipe, exit-code

Say I have a command that looks similar to the following:

`VAR=$(python SomeScript | tee /dev/null)`

I would like to get the exit code of python script but not really sure how with the assignment being in the same command.

Comment: `tee /dev/null` is pretty useless, what are you trying to do with this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a single exit code to return, you can extract and `exit` with it to make that the exit code of the whole command substitution:

```
var=$(
  python -c 'import sys; print("hi"); sys.exit(42)' | cat
  exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
)
ret=$?
echo "The output is $var and the exit code is $ret"
```

This results in:

```
The output is hi and the exit code is 42
```

If you need to extract multiple exit statuses, you'll have to write them to a file 
 or the end of the stream, and then read them back or extract them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```sh
var="$(python SomeScript)" >/dev/null
echo "SomeScript exit code: $?"
```